# How to alter colors in mac/cocoa text views

Tags: cocoa, macos, text

Is there a way to alter the standard background and text colors in cocoa text views throughout the mac os? Since the same text system is used by textedit, mail and other programs, I imagine there is an underlying preference that could be altered. Any ideas how to access it?

Just to be clear, I don't mean simply to alter the *document* colors. This shouldn't be setting a background color or text color as document formatting. I'm just wondering about how I could make all of these text views use different defaults when displaying documents (e.g. white on blue, rather than black on white).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no supported way to do this but you might achieve it with a custom [Application Enhancer](http://unsanity.com/haxies/ape) module. Note, however, this is a very controversial subject as poorly-written APE modules (or bugs in Application Enhancer itself) can cause a whole lot of pain in very unusual places (and blame is often placed on the wrong developer as a result).